# ElementCriteriaModel UTF-8 Encoding

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel

I have been working with data received from Guzzle and it is producing a Unicode String that looks similar to this `Bachelor\u2019s Degree` (after some parsing). When I save other content within craft through `craft()->entries->saveEntry( $entry )` The unicode items are converted to their appropriate characters. However, when I use this in the ElementCriteriaModel searches, it does not work because it is using the literal `Bachelor\u2019s Degree`. It does work when I hard code `Bachelor's Degree` so the lookup code is functional. Also, I tried all of the `StringHelper` static functions and have done tons of iterations of `mb_convert_encoding( 'Bachelor\u2019s Degree', 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8' )`, `htmlspecialchars`, and `htmlentities`, but it has not produced a good result. Here is the code I am using for the query just in case:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria( ElementType::Category );
$criteria->title = $job[ 'eduReq' ];
$eduReq = $criteria->first();
```

Do you all know how to convert this string correctly so that the ElementCriteriaModel uses `Bachelor's Degree`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this maybe be a unicode issue? Maybe the api plugin is producing \u2019 instead of the unicode to produce a normal `'`